# Finding matching String in two Lists of Lists

Tags: python, string, list, random

I was trying to make a function so that random values from the 'next' list are assigned to 'One' and 'Two'.  If the value that is assigned to 'One' and 'Two' coincide with the position of the values [i][0] and [i][2] in 'roundTwo' then 'One' and 'Two' are assigned new values.

After this the values 'one' and 'two' are then removed from the 'next' list.

As an example, if 'one' was to be assigned 'J090' and 'two' was to be assigned 'MA78', then they would both be assigned new values, as in 'roundTwo' there is:

> ['JO90', '1', 'MA78', '8']

However, if 'one' was assigned 'J090' and 'two' was assigned 'B208' it would be correct and the program would then continue to remove 'J090' and 'B208' from the 'next' list.

Below is an example of my code, apologies if what I have written doesn't make 
too much sense here, so just ask if you think it needs editing!

```
nextList = ['JO90', 'MA78', 'FE29', 'HT27', 'EQ37', 'BF50', 'LJ93', 'UT21', 'KJ40', 'WE82', 'WQ28', 'BV98', 'FE32', 'EF10', 'SA14', 'SP16']
roundTwo = [['JO90', '1', 'MA78', '8'], ['B208', '2', 'DF18', '3'], ['PD06', '5', 'BS07', '7'], ['SA14', '4', 'SP16', '7']]
one = nextList[random.randint(0, len(nextList) - 1)]
two = nextList[random.randint(0, len(nextList) - 1)]
for i in nextList:
    if one in roundTwo[i][0] and two in roundTwo[i][2]:  
        one = roundTwo[random.randint(0, len(roundTwo) - 1)]
        two = roundTwo[random.randint(0, len(roundTwo) - 1)]
if one in nextList:
    nextList.remove(one)
if two in nextList:
    nextList.remove(two)
```

I am getting this error when running through and I am not quite sure how to make it work correctly:

> if one in roundTwo[i][0] and two in roundTwo[i][2]:
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Thanks!

Comment: fix your indentation and don't use `next` as a variable name it's very confusing. Then include _full traceback_ of your error

Comment: is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

So if I've understood this correctly, your function does the following:

1. Take two values at random from `nextList`
2. Check whether they match a pair from `roundTwo`
3. Result of check:

   - If they *don't* match, remove them from `nextList`
   - If they *do* match, choose another two

But do you really mean just choose another two? Or do you mean go back to step 1. and repeat until you get two that don't match? Or do you not choose another two at all?

---

Your error comes from looping over `nextList` to get your `i` values (eg 'JO90', 'MA78') and then trying to look these up as indexes in your `roundTwo` list. If you want to loop over all the little sets of 4 in `roundTwo` to check against , that bit of your script should look like:

```
for item in roundTwo:  # eg item = ['JO90', '1', 'MA78', '8']
    if one == item[0] and two == item[2]:
        # choose new one and two
```

If they do match a pair from `roundTwo`, your function currently seems to try to choose alternatives somehow from the `roundTwo` list, but I think this is a typo and should be `nextList`, but without knowing more details of what your function is doing I can't say.

---

If I can guess that you'r algorithm is supposed to do the following:

1. Take two values at random from `nextList`
2. Check whether they match a pair from `roundTwo`
3. Result of check:

   - If they *don't* match, remove them from `nextList`
   - If they *do* match, start again to step 1.

Then this code should work:

```
import random

nextList = ['JO90', 'MA78', 'FE29', 'HT27', 'EQ37', 'BF50', 'LJ93', 'UT21', 'KJ40', 'WE82', 'WQ28', 'BV98', 'FE32', 'EF10', 'SA14', 'SP16']
roundTwo = [['JO90', '1', 'MA78', '8'], ['B208', '2', 'DF18', '3'], ['PD06', '5', 'BS07', '7'], ['SA14', '4', 'SP16', '7']]

while True:
    # choose one and two at random
    one = nextList[random.randint(0, len(nextList) - 1)]
    two = nextList[random.randint(0, len(nextList) - 1)]
    # loop over every set in roundTwo
    for i in roundTwo:
        # check whether one and two match
        if one == i[0] and two == i[2]:
            print "Bad pair: {0}, {1}".format(one, two)
            # break out of for loop
            # will hit end of while loop and start again
            break
    # got to end of for loop without breaking, so *didn't* match pair in roundTwo
    else:
        print "Good pair: {0}, {1}".format(one, two)
        nextList.remove(one)
        nextList.remove(two)
        # we found a good pair, so can break out of the while loop
        break
```

This will currently produce an error if `one` and `two` come out as the same. If you want them to be different, you could add a check immediately after you choose them:

```
if one == two:
    print "They're the same"
    continue
```

The `continue` will jump back to the start of the `while` loop.

Or if you are allowed to have the same, you need to add a check whether they're in `nextList` before you remove them (like you had in your original script) but you should only need to check for `two` - at least `one` should always be in the list:

```
nextList.remove(one)
if two in nextList:
    nextList.remove(two)
```

---

This uses the `for`-`else` construction: if you finish the `for` loop and haven't broken out of it sooner, then Python executes the `else` branch. This `else` branch contains a `break` statement to get out of the `while True` loop, which would otherwise go round forever. I suggest you read the Python tutorial on this if you haven't come across `while True` loops before, or `else` branches on `for` loops, or `break` statements: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html